# Why does Promise.prototype.then allow skipping reject function and allow comma at the end?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Recently I stumbled upon the `Promise.then` example on MDN just before this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#nesting

The example uses this:

```
.then((url) =>
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        listOfIngredients.push(data);
      }), // Note this comma here
  )
```

In simple terms this is equivalent to the following:

```
.then(successFunc,);
```

To my surprise, this actually doesn't throw any error. Following works, but why?

```js
const speakPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {        
        resolve("success");
    }, 500);    
});



speakPromise.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data, " End code");
}, ); // Note the trailing comma here
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a feature specifically for `.then`? Did you try any other function call `console.log(1,)`?

Comment: Related: [Trailing comma in JavaScript function call](/q/43339356/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to `.then()`. Simply trailing commas are allowed in function calls:

```js
console.log(1,);
```

This was added to the [ECMAScript 2017 specification, section 12.3, syntax for arguments](https://262.ecma-international.org/8.0/#prod-Arguments):

```
Arguments [Yield, Await]  :
    ( )
    ( ArgumentList [?Yield, ?Await] )
    ( ArgumentList [?Yield, ?Await] , )
```

The original proposal was [proposal-trailing-function-commas by  Jeff Morrison](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-trailing-function-commas). The rationale was to allow more easily adding arguments in newlines without producing unnecessary noise in version control systems such as Git. Normally updating code like

```
finctionCall(
    "one",
    "two"
)
```

to add an argument would produce:

```
finctionCall(
    "one",
-   "two"
+   "two",
+   "three",
)
```

but with trailing commas the difference is much cleaner:

```
finctionCall(
    "one",
    "two",
)
```

updates to

```
finctionCall(
    "one",
    "two",
+   "three",
)
```

Moreover, there is no adverse effects to allowing `fn(arg1,)` and `fn(arg1, arg2,)` they are still treated as `fn(arg1)` and `fn(arg1, arg2)`.

See also: [MDN article on Trailing commas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#function_calls)

Answer (score 0):

The `then` function has the signature `then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`.

The documentation says:

> If one or both arguments are omitted or are provided non-functions,
> then they will be missing the handler(s), but will not generate any
> errors.

```js
function f(...args) {
  console.log(args.length)
}
f(5)
f(6,)
f(7,8)
```

As you can see from the code above, a comma with no argument after it will be treated by javascript as if you'd simply not specified a second argument. Therefore, the presence or absence of a comma makes no difference when no argument follows it.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the documentation. I found a related useful reference as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#:~:text=Trailing%20commas%20(sometimes%20called%20%22final,already%20uses%20a%20trailing%20comma.

Comment: @user31782 this is the doc I got it from https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/promise/then